# Flutter: How to improve Image.memory performance

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app where the user uploads/takes pictures. I achieve this functionality using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package. Before uploading those images, I display the images to the user to allow them to remove them and view them. I am using an `AnimatedList()` for that. when removing an item, I have a `SizeTransition()` which then returns a container with an `Image.memory()` child. The problem is that this is not performant and the widget basically disappears and I don't see any frames in between. If I remove the picture, the animation happens smoothly.

How can I make it performant or use another way to display the images so that they are performant? Do I compress the image? Change its size? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) to resize and compress the images which seemed to work. It is a lot more performant now.